# How to render website from other kubernetes pod on my pod?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to render flower, which lies in a kubernetes pod, in my other web-interface pod. Is there anyway how I can adress the service from outside the cluster, since the rendering happens in my computer and not on the pod.

I tried NodePort but it's not working. I used something like this but it cannot reach the server. I am quite new to kubernetes and would appreciate any help.

'''http://celery-flowe-service:5555'''

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the service from a different pod in same cluster using a service DNS in kuberentes. Kubernetes internally create a DNS for every service you create.

The internal DNS inside cluster will be

```
<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local
```

Example, if your service name is test-service and is deployed in namespace default, then

```
test-service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Using the above DNS, you can access the service running to the connect POD from within the cluster.

If you want to connect to it from outside cluster, you can create a External Load Balancer. Use service as `Load Balancer` and using this, you can access from outside cluster.

If you go with more advanced kuberentes deployment, you can use Ingress/Traefik Controllers to expose your services in Kubernetes.